# Android MySQL Check if the user is admin or not

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-volley

I have a login form, where the user will input their USERNAME and Password.

What i want to achieve is:

•Checks if the user is admin , manager , normal user.

•Then i will display a toast/echo that the user is an admin / manager / normal user

This is my current source code for the login form.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class TwoFragment extends Fragment{
View view;
    Button reg;



    //Defining views
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonLogin;


    //boolean variable to check user is logged in or not
    //initially it is false
    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    public TwoFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
        reg = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        buttonLogin = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnsignin);
        buttonLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                login();
            }
        });

        editTextEmail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        reg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), managerreg.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });



        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //In onresume fetching value from sharedpreference
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getContext().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        //Fetching the boolean value form sharedpreferences
        loggedIn = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, false);

        //If we will get true
        if(loggedIn){
            //We will start the Profile Activity
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void login(){
        //Getting values from edit texts
        final String username = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();



        //Creating a string request
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Config.LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        //If we are getting success from server
                        if(response.equalsIgnoreCase(Config.LOGIN_SUCCESS)){
                            //Creating a shared preference
                            SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                            //Creating editor to store values to shared preferences
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                            //Adding values to editor
                            editor.putBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF, true);
                            editor.putString(Config.USERNAME_SHARED_PREF,username );


                            //Saving values to editor
                            editor.commit();

                            //Starting profile activity
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }else{
                            //If the server response is not success
                            //Displaying an error message on toast
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        //You can handle error here if you want
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Adding parameters to request
                params.put(Config.KEY_USERNAME, username);
                params.put(Config.KEY_PASSWORD, password);


                //returning parameter
                return params;
            }
        };

        //Adding the string request to the queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }



}
```

This is my current php:

```
<?php

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];




        require_once('dbConnect.php');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM managerreg WHERE username = '$username' AND password = BINARY '".md5($_POST['password'])." ";

        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        $check = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        if(isset($check)){
            echo 'success';
        }else{
            echo 'failure';
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to check if the user is an admin or not.

Comment: Could you tell what's your trouble?

Comment: Btw, your PHP code is vulnerable to SQLInj. If someone passes ' <- this char inside his username, you're in trouble. See here: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: I don't know how to check if the user is an admin or not.

Answer (score 0):

Well when you pass the username and password to the service, your response should also include a data like userid or something so that you can compare it in your program and then get to know who has logged in to the application.

Comment: How to put data in the variable from the php?